# Unable to start pgagent after installation rpm in suse linux

Tags: postgresql, service, installation, suse, pgagent

I have installed PgAgent in my suse linux VM from the rpm:

```
postgresql10-pgagent-4.0.0-2.4.x86_64.rpm
```

But after resolving dependencies , I and unable to run the pgagent command

Getting the following:

> If 'pgagent' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
>       cnf pgagent

```
rpm -ql postgresql10-pgagent
```

gives me the following:

[image]

Comment: Run `rpm -ql postgresql10-pgagent` to find out the name of the executable and the directory where it is.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i ran rpm -ql postgresql10-pgagent , edited the post and attached screenshot of the ouput

Answer (score 0):

From your listing, the executable seems to be

```
/usr/bin/postgresql10-pgagent
```

I guess that the packagers included the PostgreSQL version in the executable name because they want to be able to install pgagent for several PostgreSQL versions in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz , the executable was present in /usr/bin/ .

Comment: But Still getting the following error 
./postgresql10-pgagent: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.69.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have that library on your system? Use `locate`. If yes, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the directory where the library is. If not, file a bug with the packager.